# How to loop through several columns to generate multiple crosstabs

Tags: r, loops, crosstab

I'm trying to create a document that has several crosstabs using multiple y variables and a single x variable. Each y variable should have a separate table. I can do this with each individual crosstab in markdown and use the kableextra package to generate the html tables. However, I have several variables and it would just be easier to do this with one loop. In Stata, I would so something like:

```
foreach i of varlist var1 var2 var3 {
  tab tab `i' year, row
}
```

The issue that I'm having with Stata is that it doesn't apply frequency weights in tab. R does apply frequency weights in the crosstab (descr package), and it produces row and column percents.

Here is a sample dataframe:

```
structure(list(survey_yr = c(2019, 2020, 2019, 2020, 2019, 2020, 
2019, 2020, 2019, 2020, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2019, 
2020, 2019, 2020), Main_Data = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Survey_Month = c(6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9), Quarter = c(1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Q1A_3L = c(3, 
1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2), Q1B_3L = c(3, 
1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2), Q1C_3L = c(3, 
1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2), Q1D_3L = c(3, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2), Q1E_3L = c(3, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2), Q1F_3L = c(3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2), Q1G_3L = c(3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2), Q1H_3L = c(3, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2), Q1I_3L = c(3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2), Q1J_3L = c(3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2), Q1K_3L = c(3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2), Q1L_3L = c(3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2), Q1M_3L = c(3, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2), Q1N_3L = c(3, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2), Q1O_3L = c(3, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2), Q1P_3L = c(3, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2), Q1Q_3L = c(3, 
1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2), Q2_3L = c(3, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2), weight = c(0.680000007152557, 
0.680000007152557, 0.823000013828278, 0.823000013828278, 0.823000013828278, 
0.823000013828278, 0.823000013828278, 0.823000013828278, 0.823000013828278, 
0.823000013828278, 1.27100002765656, 0.823000013828278, 0.823000013828278, 
0.823000013828278, 0.823000013828278, 0.823000013828278, 0.823000013828278, 
1.57599997520447, 0.823000013828278, 0.823000013828278)), row.names = c(4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
23L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 31L, 33L), class = "data.frame")
```

The code that I've been using for the single crosstab, which produces a really nice table is:

```
ct2=crosstab(dat$Q2_3L,dat$survey_yr, weight = dat$weight, 
       total.c = T, plot = F)
ct2_tab<- descr:::CreateNewTab(ct2)
class(ct2_tab)
kable(ct2_tab) %>%
  kable_classic(full_width = F, html_font = "Cambria")
```

I would like to figure out a way to write a loop that does this over multiple columns. This is close, but I want specific columns, not all columns in the dataframe. Secondly, it renames the actual column name to "col", while I need to keep the original column names. Finally, I can't figure out how to export this to an html, docx, excel, or whatever type of document.

```
for (col in df) {
  ct_=crosstab(col, dat1$survey_yr, 
      weight = dat1$weight, format = "SPSS", prop.c = T, plot = F)
 print(ct_)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What packages are you using? Especially for `crosstab` ?

Comment: I'm using the descr package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use

```r
library(descr)

for (col in names(df)[5:22]) {
  ct_ <- crosstab(df[[col]], 
                  df[["survey_yr"]], 
                  weight = df[["weight"]], 
                  format = "SAS", 
                  prop.c = TRUE, 
                  plot = FALSE)
  ct_[["RowData"]] <- col
  ct_[["ColData"]] <- "survey_yr"
  print(ct_)
}
```

The `names(df)[5:22]` iterates over the columns like "Q1H_3". This returns something like

```r
   Cell Contents 
|-------------------------|
|                       N | 
|           N / Col Total | 
|-------------------------|

===============================
          survey_yr
Q1Q_3L     2019    2020   Total
-------------------------------
1             1       2       3
          0.125   0.222        
-------------------------------
2             0       2       2
          0.000   0.222        
-------------------------------
3             7       5      12
          0.875   0.556        
-------------------------------
Total         8       9      17
          0.471   0.529        
===============================
   Cell Contents 
|-------------------------|
|                       N | 
|           N / Col Total | 
|-------------------------|

==============================
         survey_yr
Q2_3L     2019    2020   Total
------------------------------
1            1       3       4
         0.125   0.333        
------------------------------
2            0       2       2
         0.000   0.222        
------------------------------
3            7       4      11
         0.875   0.444        
------------------------------
Total        8       9      17
         0.471   0.529        
==============================
```

#### Print to txt

You can save this output to a file (for example a .txt-file) using `sink()`:

```r
for (col in names(df)[5:22]) {
  sink(file = paste0(col, ".txt"))
  ct_ <- crosstab(df[[col]], 
                  df[["survey_yr"]], 
                  weight = df[["weight"]], 
                  format = "SAS", 
                  prop.c = TRUE, 
                  plot = FALSE)
  ct_[["RowData"]] <- col
  ct_[["ColData"]] <- "survey_yr"
  print(ct_)
  sink()
}
```

This creates multiple files in your current working directory, for example Q1A_3L.txt and Q1B_3L.txt.

Comment: I accidentally changed `format = "SPSS"` to `format = "SAS"`. This slightly changes the output. Change it back, if necessary.

Comment: Thank you. This looks almost exactly how I want it. A couple of questions: Is it possible to select columns that aren't in order, for example if I want column 7, 15, 22, 7? And is it possible to merge all of the .txt files into one .txt file?

Comment: (1) You can change `5:22` to `c(7, 15, 22,7)`. (2) To merge everything into one file you could move the `sink()` functions outside the `for` loops.

Comment: How to save multiple crosstables in to one excel file?

Comment: @Laura do you want them on one sheet or multiple sheets?

Comment: In one sheet. In fact, I want to append them next to each other because they have the same number of rows.